# Python - Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error, arcgis, arcmap

I can't figure out what's wrong with the syntax in line 9 below. Help? Using Python in ArcMap.

```
>>> for strName in rasterList:
...     pRaster = arcpy.Raster(strName)
...     pPoint = arcpy.Point(2256560.829028871, 908394.8188188977)
...     if pRaster.name == "dem":
...         myArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(pRaster, pPoint, 3, 3)
...         (width, height)= myArray.shape
...         for row in range(0,height):
...             for col in range(0,width):
...                 print "["+ str(row) + ", " + str(col)+"]:"str(myArray.item(row,col))
...                 
Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 9)
```

Comment: You are missing a + between `print "["+ str(row) + ", " + str(col)+"]:"` and `str(myArray.item(row,col))`

Comment: @Francesco - that seems more appropriately an answer than a comment.

Comment: @Robᵩ thanks, i'm still trying to figure out when to comment, answer, edit

Comment: @Francesco Simply if your comment helps to solve the problem, delete your comment and make it an answer

Comment: And that's why you use string formatting and not this concatenation stuff ...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a + between `print "["+ str(row) + ", " + str(col)+"]:"` and `str(myArray.item(row,col))`

Comment: Ahh okay. Thank you.